# Function of a formula in python for big dataset

Tags: python, pandas

Say, I need to convert the following formula into python and use it on a data frame. The formula is as follows.

[image]

The data frame has got values for Xj and Bj. The data frame looks like the following.

```
 df.head()
type name   OR
1   SAP1    11.21
1   SAP1    1301
2   SAP1    0.7578
2   LUF1    1447
2   LUF1    0.7578
1   ANK3    1150
1   ANK3    0.9909
1   ANK3    1535
1   ACR     0.9909
1   ACR     1535
```

The above data frame has got values for `Xj=type` and `bj=OR` from the data frame. I need for each `sam` The `^S` score from the formula
In the end, for each `name`, I need a single `S` score.

I have implemented something like this,

```
   def score(df):
        df_sum   =df[['type','name','OR']].groupby('name').sum().reset_index()
        sum   =df_sum['type']
        OR=df_sum['OR']
        score=sum([sum*OR])
        return score
```

The question is I need to get them for each `name` value single score not many scores for all repeating `name` values. In the end, I need only 4 rows with 4 score values.

It is possible on small datasets. However, when I give a big data frame with multiple `name` values for `OR` and `type` columns. Then I have multiple scores for the same `name`

Note: The values in column `type` are binaries. Hence, I am not sure I am use in grouby to count or sum it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum product and groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50841829/sum-product-and-groupby)

Comment: The solution there gives me different score than from my formula

Comment: The values in type are binaries. 1 means yes and 2 no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you change the order of opérations you can have the expected result:

1 calculate xi*bi

```
df['xibi'] =df ['type'] * df['OR']
```

2 groupby and sum

```
res=df.groupby('name')['xibi'].sum()
```